# Get Country from tzInfo TimeZone?

Tags: ruby, localization, timezone, tzinfo

Given a tzInfo `TimeZone` object such as `'America/New_York`' how can I get the associated country (countries?) that would use the time zone with this identifier?

The instance methods don't link back to countries:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/Timezone

My problem description:

- I receive scientific datasets produced in a certain timezone given with the long zone identifier (fortunately!). These datasets were not stored with geolocalization turned on, so the timezone is a first identifier where data was produced.
- Turning the timezone into friendly identifiers is a first step to understand their origin, but many zone names are quite esoteric (America/Menominee?), so it would be great to do the reverse look-up from timezone to list of countries that support that zone.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that information? I can imagine a situation where a time zone ID is shared between multiple countries. (I don't know if that's actually the case at the moment, but it might be for at least a while if a country splits in two, for example.)

Comment: Purely for information. Everyone knows where New_York is, but America/Bahia_Banderas?

Comment: https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone.tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a direct way, but you can use the [`Country` class](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/Country) to build a hash that maps zone names to country names.

You can loop through the countries (using `all` method) and get the zone identifiers for each country (using `zone_identifiers` method) to build the hash.

I don't code in Ruby very often, so probably it's not the best Ruby-style code, but it's something like this:

```
# map zones to countries
ztc = {}

TZInfo::Country.all().each do |c|
  c.zone_identifiers.each do |z|
    ztc[z] = [] unless ztc.has_key?(z)
    ztc[z].push(c.name)
  end
end
```

`ztc` will contain the zone names as keys, and an array of the respective country names as values. In my machine, I've got:

```
{"Europe/Andorra"=>["Andorra"],
 "Asia/Dubai"=>["United Arab Emirates", "Oman"],
 "Asia/Kabul"=>["Afghanistan"],
 "America/Port_of_Spain"=>["Antigua & Barbuda", "Anguilla", "St Barthelemy", "Dominica",
                           "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "St Kitts & Nevis", "St Lucia",
                           "St Martin (French)", "Montserrat", "Trinidad & Tobago",
                           "St Vincent", "Virgin Islands (UK)", "Virgin Islands (US)"],
  ....
```

Just reminding that it'll contain only timezones that are associated with countries (the ones with the format `Region/City`, like `Europe/London` or `America/New_York`). So names like `GMT` or `Etc/GMT+1` won't be in that list.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Hugo's answer, a short extension to `class Timezone`:

```
module TZInfo

class Timezone

    def countries
        return Timezone::country_map[self.name] || []
    end

    @@countryMap = nil

    def self.country_map
        if @@countryMap.nil?
          @@countryMap = {}

            TZInfo::Country.all().each do |c|
                c.zone_identifiers.each do |z|
                    @@countryMap[z] ||= [] 
                    @@countryMap[z] << c.name
                end
            end
        end
        return @@countryMap
    end

end

end
```